# Ubuntu / PopOS 21.04 - Screen blinking

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, intel, intel-graphics, pop-os

I just bought a Fusion Serie from PCSpecialist and I'm having screen issue when running Ubuntu (tested 20.04 and 21.04) or PopOS (tested 21.04)

- built-in screen display is blinking when the mouse cursor is moving within its display area using the touchpad or a mouse
- if I press the left button while moving the cursor the display does not blink
- when using an external monitor its display is fine, but not the integrated screen one (in duplicated or extended mode)
- I recorded the screen and the video is not showing the blinks (although the screen was blinking while recording)

What I tried:

- changing screens resolutions
- enabling / disabling PopOS HiDPI daemon
- use different kernels (from 5.11 to 5.14)

Here are the laptop specs:

- Chassis & Display: Fusion Studio Series : Écran large LED mat 14 pouces 90 Hz sRGB 95 % WQXGA (2880 x 1800)
- Processor (CPU): Processeur Quad Core Intel® Core® i7 11370H (3,3 GHz, 4,8 GHz Turbo)
- Memory (RAM): 16 Go Corsair 2933 MHz SODIMM DDR4 (2 x 8 Go)
- Graphics Card: Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics
- 1st M.2 SSD Drive: 500 Go SAMSUNG 970 EVO PLUS M.2, PCIe NVMe

And some commands outputs (from PopOS 21.04):

```
uname -r
5.11.0-7633-generic

inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
           Device-2: Chicony HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting
           unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1: 1440x900~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.1

sudo lshw -c video
*-display                
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=2880x1800 visual=truecolor xres=2880 yres=1800
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:153 memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Tongfang Hongkong Limited Iris Xe Graphics [1d05:1105]
```

Full probe of my system: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=9361e69812

I don't really know which potential fixes I should start with therefore any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

NOTE: I also have W10 installed along side PopOS and W10 is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounter this post, I ended up following [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389799/1423753) from @holgerstrunk with nice results:

Just had this problem on the exact same processor. It turned out that an Intel power-optimization feature has to be turned off via grub.

Add "i915.enable_psr=0" to the default GRUB command line in /etc/defaults/grub, so it reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
```

The flickering is gone after activating this GRUB.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Please copy (or paraphrase) the answer (yes, [it’s allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)). Keep the link and add the author’s name.